# syslog-ng value mapping for variable sub-string

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

i'm running syslog-ng in container `balabit/syslog-ng:3.35.1`

i would like to do value mapping for value in `vpnrd` variable

Below is config for value mapping + example of CSV file

```json
parser p_json {
    json-parser(prefix(".json."));
};

parser p_acd_vrf {
    add-contextual-data(
        selector("${.json.vpnrd}")
        database("vrf_map.csv")
        default-selector("UNKNOWN")
        prefix(".meta_vrf.")
    );
};
```

Content of CSV file:

```
111,vrf_id,vrf_1
222,vrf_id,vrf_2
zzz,vrf_id,vrf_example
UNKNOWN,vrf_id,[No VRF; Global Instance peer]
...
```

The problem is that `vpnrd` contains string in format `xxx:yyy:zzz` and I need to split it (delimiter `:`) and use only last section `zzz` because only that part is relevant for value mapping.

Is there the way to do it in syslog-ng?

I was looking at custom python parser where it would be easy to do this kind of operation but then I don't know how to connect result of python parser with value mapping parser.

thanks for any pointers

---

Update: i wrote python parser based on [this blog](https://www.syslog-ng.com/community/b/blog/posts/analyze-your-suricata-logs-in-real-time-using-syslog-ng) but unfortunately mapping still does not work and I always get `[No VRF; Global Instance peer]` which is mapped as default value.
I also can't see the logs from python script (where are they sent?) so it's hard to tshoot what is going on

```py
parser p_py_vrf_id {
    python(
        class("GetVrfId")
    );
};

python {
from syslogng import Logger
logger = Logger()
class GetVrfId(object):
    def parse(self, log_message):
        """
        extract vrf_id from rd variable
        """
        logger.info(f'log: {log_message}')
        try:
            vpnrd = log_message['.json.rd'].split(':')[-1].strip()
            log_message['.json.vpnrd'] = vpnrd
            logger.info(f'vpnrd: {vpnrd}')
        except KeyError:
            log_message['.json.vpnrd'] = 'UNKNOWN'
            logger.error(f'key-error: rd not present')
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f'catch-all-error: {e}')
        # return True, other way message is dropped
        return True
};
```

Comment: `log_message['.json.vpnrd'] = vpnrd` should do the trick. Please note that `LogMessage` fields are bytes objects in Python 3, so you might want to decode them into a string before transforming them (for example: `log_message['.json.vpnrd'].decode("utf8")`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options here, one of them is writing your own parser in Python.

Parsers usually produce new name-value pairs. The connection between `add-contextual-data()` and your parser would be the key you specify in `selector()`.

`LogMessage` fields are bytes objects in Python 3, so they have to be decoded into strings before transforming them (for example: `log_message['.json.vpnrd'].decode("utf-8")`).

`syslogng.Logger` logs into the `internal()` source.

---

`xxx:yyy:zzz` seems to be a fixed length, so you can just remove the unnecessary parts (no custom parser is required):

```
parser p_acd_vrf {
    add-contextual-data(
        selector("$(substr ${.json.vpnrd} 8)")
        database("vrf_map.csv")
        prefix(".meta_vrf.")
    );
};
```

Alternatively, [`$(explode)`](https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/pull/2700) can be used to split the string into a list (+ `$(list-nth)` to select the last element).

---

Another option is to use the built-in `csv-parser()`, configuring `:` as the separator character.

Comment: hi, thanks for inspiration. `vpnrd` is not fix length, I might have provided misleading example.` xxx` part is fix length, `yyy` is IP address (not fix length character-wise) and last part `zzz` is variable length. Additionally `vpnrd` is optional element in json message so it might not be present in every message. I think best way to cover all cases will be custom Python parser to either return only sub-string or some default value if  `vpnrd` is not part of the json and then to the mapping based on that...now the hard part, create config for that :)

Comment: In that case, an if-else block can be used together with the $(explode) template function. After splitting it conditionally into a list, the 3rd element can be selected easily.

Comment: adding log for `internal` + `.decode("utf-8")` fixed both problems, now I can see logs and python parser works as expected, thank!